# Trouble setting up JDK in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
COMPANY-0034:Home deter_dangler$ pwd
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
COMPANY-0034:Home deter_dangler$ ls
README.html conf        jmods       lib
bin     include     legal       release
COMPANY-0034:Home deter_dangler$
```

Terminal shows I have JDK 9.0 installed and I configured JAVA SE 9.0 in eclipse as below:

[image]

But when I am trying configure build path for any Java project as below, it shows Native Library Location as 'None' and shows errors in my .Java file:

[image]

What is missing?

**EDIT**:

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you running? I bet you're running an old version that doesn't support Java 9. You need Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a or later.

Comment: Kepler is old (4.3). Java 8 wasn't even added until 4.4 (Luna), though Kepler could use Java 8. Upgrade your Eclipse to 4.7.2 (Oxygen.2).

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Not sure why I downloaded the old version. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Eclipse's website, [(here)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9), Java 9 is only officially supported on Eclipse Oxygen.

If you can, I recommend upgrading to Oxygen so you can avoid compatibility issues.